# How to get a substring out of a string several times

Tags: python, string

I try to get a specific substring out of a string as often as it apears in Python.
The substring will be different every time, but the structure will be the same.

Example:

```
[{u'style': u'opacity:0.58800001;fill:#0000ff;fill-opacity:1;
stroke:none;stroke-width:3.47952747;
stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;
stroke-dashoffset:0;stroke-opacity:1', u'id': u'rect5231', u'd': 

u'm 0,1016.9291 35.433071,0 0,35.433 -35.433071,0 z

'},{u'style': u'opacity:0.58800001;fill:#0000ff;fill-opacity:1;
stroke:none;stroke-width:3.47952747;stroke-linecap:round;
stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;
stroke-dashoffset:0;stroke-opacity:1', u'id': u'rect5233', u'd':

 u'm 70.866142,1016.9291 35.433068,0 0,35.433 -35.433068,0 z

'}]
```

Thats the string I have and I only need seperates substring beginning with "m..."
I tried str.split but it removes to much an only output the second marked substring.

Comment: this is list of dicts. iterate over the list and access the respective key in each dict.

Comment: is the whole example one big string? Or as the previous comment says, is this a list of dictionaries? In python, how are you inputting this data?

Comment: It should be one big string. It's a tuple which was convertet to a string.

Comment: show the correct input. Of course, the question is why would you convert it to str, when working with list/tuple of dicts is way easier in this case... Don't hesitate to address this question

Comment: easy, because the program I then put the data in only accepts string and dont like tuple^^

Comment: but, you will extract the value for key 'd', which value is the sub-string you want and it is str and if I understand correctly that is what you pass to some other software. As it stands now, your question is example of XY problem

Comment: Please post your code and an example of what output you are expecting. Consider using regular expressions. In particular `re.findall` may be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Having one string you can use `find()` method in a `while loop`. Starting with the beginning of your string, you look for the first occurrence with `find()` method, which returns you the index of the beginning of the substring, then you start again but this time starting with an index after the one, found by previous `find()`. And so on unless `find()` returns `-1`.

In order to find a substring according to some pattern in your string you can use `re` module for regular expressions

Answer (score 0):

```
data = [{u'style': u'...dummy style...', u'id': u'rect5231', u'd':u'm 0,1016.9291 35.433071,0 0,35.433 -35.433071,0 z'},
       {u'style': u'...dummy style...', u'id': u'rect5233', u'd':u'm 70.866142,1016.9291 35.433068,0 0,35.433 -35.433068,0 z'}]

for item in data:
    d_value = item.get('d')
    print(d_value)
    print(type(d_value))
```

output

```
m 0,1016.9291 35.433071,0 0,35.433 -35.433071,0 z
<class 'str'>
m 70.866142,1016.9291 35.433068,0 0,35.433 -35.433068,0 z
<class 'str'>
```

As you can see it's easy to retrieve the value you want and it is a `str`